# PHP - Merge inner arrays within a multi-dimensional array if a specific element matches

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [name] => size
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Medium
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [name] => colour
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Orange
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [name] => size
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Medium
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [name] => colour
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Green
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [name] => size
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Medium
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [name] => colour
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Pink
        )

)
```

As you can see there are six inner arrays and the product_id field matches twice for each value, so there are three pairs.

I'd like to merge the "name" and "value" fields of each inner array into just the value field if the "product_id" field matches.

I'm aiming to end up with this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Size: Medium, Colour: Orange
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Size: Medium, Colour: Green
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Size: Medium, Colour: Pink
        )
)
```

Which PHP function should I be using and how?

Comment: You've shown zero programming effort. I highly suggest trying some code and explaining at which point you are stuck. There is no magical function which performs this exact merge so you can either use a `foreach()` loop and build your array the way you need or browse [PHP's array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and see what could be useful.

Comment: My apologies. I'm new to this. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function format_result($tab) {

    // return array
    $ret = Array();

    // Search and fill ret
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tab); $i++) {
        $tmp = array();
        $first = true;
        for($j = $i+1; $j < count($tab); $j++) {
            if($tab[$i]["product_id"] == $tab[$j]["product_id"]) {
                // If same product_id then format result
                if($first) {
                    $tmp = array(
                        "product_id" =>$tab[$i]["product_id"],
                        "lang_key" => $tab[$i]["lang_key"],
                        "value" => ucfirst($tab[$i]["name"]).': '.$tab[$i]["value"].", ".ucfirst($tab[$j]["name"]).': '.$tab[$j]["value"]
                    );
                    $first = false;
                } else {
                    $tmp["value"] .= ", ".ucfirst($tab[$j]["name"]).': '.$tab[$j]["value"];
                }
            }
        }
        if(count($tmp) == 0) {
            $tmp = $tab[$i];
        }
        $ret[] = $tmp;
    }
    // delete bad inserted lines
    for($i = 0; $i < count($ret); $i++) {
        for($j = $i+1; $j < count($ret); $j++) {
            if($ret[$i]["product_id"] == $ret[$j]["product_id"]) {
                array_splice($ret,$j,1);
                $j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Using:

```
$mydata = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            "product_id" => 1,
            "name" => "size",
            "lang_key" => "en",
            "value" => "Medium",
        ),
    1 => Array
        (
            "product_id" => 1,
            "name" => "colour",
            "lang_key" => "en",
            "value" => "Orange",
        ),
    2 => Array
        (
            "product_id" => 2,
            "name" => "size",
            "lang_key" => "en",
            "value" => "Medium",
        ),
    3 => Array
        (
            "product_id" => 2,
            "name" => "colour",
            "lang_key" => "en",
            "value" => "Green",
        ),
    4 => Array
        (
            "product_id" => 3,
            "name" => "size",
            "lang_key" => "en",
            "value" => "Medium",
        ),
    5 => Array
        (
            "product_id" => 3,
            "name" => "colour",
            "lang_key" => "en",
            "value" => "Pink",
        ),
    6 => Array
        (
            "product_id" => 2,
            "name" => "what",
            "lang_key" => "en",
            "value" => "Help",
        ),
    7 => Array
        (
            "product_id" => 3,
            "name" => "language",
            "lang_key" => "en",
            "value" => "PHP",
        )
);
print_r (format_result($mydata));
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Size: Medium, Colour: Orange
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Size: Medium, Colour: Green, What: Help
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [lang_key] => en
            [value] => Size: Medium, Colour: Pink, Language: PHP
        )

)
```